# Is it possible to run Azure Logic Apps On Premise

Tags: azure, docker, hosting, workflow, azure-logic-apps

Recent announcements for [Azure logic apps says](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-developer-community-blog/new-logic-apps-runtime-performance-and-developer-improvements/ba-p/1645335)

> "With this release you can now run Logic Apps wherever you run Azure
> Functions – containerized in Docker or Kubernetes environments such as
> AKS (Azure Kubernetes Service) or App Service for a managed PaaS
> experience"

Can it be hosted in docker ? I don't see any articles related to that .

Comment: Did you see this part of the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-stateful-stateless-workflows-visual-studio-code#deploy-to-docker-container

Comment: @juunas This is about designing a logic app locally using VS code , but what I want is to host it locally in my internal network without hosting it in azure .

Comment: The part I linked to explains how you can build a Docker container out of it. You can host that container where you want.

Comment: Thanks , Got it.  The link didn't directed me to the exact place at the first time.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the documentation shows how you can package the app into a Docker container: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-stateful-stateless-workflows-visual-studio-code#deploy-to-docker-container.

From the docs:

> dotnet build -c release
>
> dotnet publish -c release
>
> docker build --tag
> local/workflowcontainer .

The example uses a dockerfile like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:3.0.14492-appservice

ENV AzureWebJobsStorage <storage-account-connection-string>
ENV AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT Development
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot
ENV AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
ENV FUNCTIONS_V2_COMPATIBILITY_MODE=true

COPY ./bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/ /home/site/wwwroot
```

The container is then run with:

> docker run -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=localhost -p 8080:80 local/workflowcontainer

Answer (score 2):

The links referenced above no longer provide information about how to do the Docker support.

Piecing the replies above together I ended up doing the following:

1. In my Logic App project in VSCode, add a DockerFile to the root of the project
2. Paste in the docker instructions as @juunas referenced:

```html
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:3.0.14492-appservice

ENV AzureWebJobsStorage={FILL-IN-YOUR-STORAGE-ACCOUNT-CONNECTION-STRING}
ENV AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT Development
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot
ENV AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
ENV FUNCTIONS_V2_COMPATIBILITY_MODE=true

COPY ./bin/release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/ /home/site/wwwroot
```

3. Run the following commands from a command prompt

```html
dotnet build -c release
dotnet publish -c release
```

4. Build the docker image

```html
docker build --tag local/workflowcontainer .
```

5. Run your container

```html
docker run -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=localhost -p 8080:80 local/workflowcontainer
```

I gathered the information above from the following website:

https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip311.html